# Android- How to change the colour of a button in xml?

Tags: android, button

How do I change the colour of a button? The actual button not the button's text.

I want to change it to green. (#00FF00)
I also want to keep the text black.

Button code:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGoPractice2"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Submit" 
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
```

Comment: `android:background="#00ff00"`

Answer (score 0):

Just do android:background="color hex value " within the button tag.

For example :

```
 android:background="#00FF00" // For Button Background
 android:textColor="#000000"  // For button Text Color
```

Hope this helps .. :)